# extend TSQL Select statement, based on bool value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find out if I can selectively include or omit content from certain tables based on a Boolean flag in one table.

There are 2 tables in question, and i'd like to do the following:

```
SELECT id, isValid From Table1

If isValid = true THEN select * from Table2
```

Basically, if a given field is true, then include another select statement, in the main `select` statement, otherwise don't.

Is this possible?

***UPDATE***
Just to make it a little clearer - and try and explain what i'm trying to achieve.

Table 1 contains 13 fields, while table 2 contains 4 fields. Both table have a relationship, using id (not the real name, just used in this example).

So, whenever field isValid is set to true in table 1, then I need all the corresponding information from table 2 where the id's match. If isValid is false, then dont select anything from table 2

Comment: You wouldn't be able to store a true boolean, you'd either have to have "true" and "false" as varchars or you could use a bit and set 1 as true and 0 as false

Comment: Could you please show some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Thorsten, this is just exploratory at the moment. I want to see if my task is possible in SQL before, moving into other areas.

Comment: You don't seem to have a relation between `Table1` and `Table2` nor filter either table. How do you test your condition ? One entry has `isValid` to `true` or all entries are `true` ?

Comment: It is still not clear what you want. Make up some sample data. Do you want to show any values of table1? And in case IsValid = 'true' for a record in table1: Do you want to show additional rows from table2 then or additional columns? Of which records of table2 exactly? Create some example illustrating what you want. Just some made-up table1 records, some for table2 and the according result records the query should produce.

Comment: Hi @ThorstenKettner, I wont to show details from table 1 at all times, and only items from table 2, where table1.IsValid = true, based on matching id's in both tables.

Comment: This is what Ghost's query does. Select all records from table1 and join table2 only when isvalid is set. Maybe it's just different IDs to compare. Ghost supposed a 1:1 relation established by using the same IDs in both tables. Maybe there is an id_table2 in table1 instead? As you *still* don't show any examples, we can only *guess*, whereas you should *know* which IDs to deal with.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I had a typo in table 2 for the id. Sorted this, and now Ghosts query is correct and has been accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you've accepted *Gordon's* answer which is just as fine, as both sent their correct answer on Sep 3 at 12:20.

Comment: Sorry, yeah. Gordon was the first to respond with the query. Thanks for pointing that out - Monday morning blues, with a cold :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `union all`:

```
select id, isValid
From Table1 t1
union all
select id, isValid
from Table2 t2
where exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.isValue = true);
```

This selects all rows from `Table1` and then only those rows from `Table2` that have a matching valid record in `Table1`.

EDIT:

I suspect you just want a `left join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.isvalid = true;
```

This returns all the columns from both tables.  If `isvalid` is not true (or there is no match in `table2`), then `table2`'s columns are `NULL`.

Comment: Hi Gordan, thanks for responding. this isnt an issue with related records, moreover, adding to the existing select statement, based on a boolean flag. As the if statment above tried to explain. if table1.IsValid = true then select * from table2 and include in original statement.

Comment: Also, to add. this approach would require operators to be equal, i.e same amount a fields in both tables - this isnt' the case for this situation.

Table1 contains 13 fields, Table2 contains 4.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee . . . Then your question doesn't really make sense.  A SQL statement can only return a fixed set of columns, not a different set for each row.

Comment: see the update above. I believe i've explained it a little better. this is one complete select statement, containing columns from the said two tables.

Comment: I had the incorrect Id value set in Table 2, so it wasn't matching. thanks

Answer (score 1):

All records from Table 1 and all records from Table 2 where the IDs match and the IsValid on Table 1 is true.

```
Select
   t1.*,t2.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID AND t1.IsValid=1
```

Comment: Ghost, this return all rows (20), for table 1 with each value for table 2 null, even for the one row in table 1 where isValid is 1. If I change to join to Right Join, then I get one row, with the information i need from table 2 and nothing for table 1

Answer (score -1):

try

```
Select id
case when isvalid = true then select * from table 2
from table1
left join table 2 on table1.id=table2.id

it really depends if is valid values is populated with string or int
```

Comment: Hi James, this appears to be invalid SQL